React + FastAPI: 404 Error When Navigating to New Route in Sidebar
I'm working on a project using the Full Stack FastAPI Template. The technology stack includes:

FastAPI for the backend with SQLModel for ORM, Pydantic for data
validation, and PostgreSQL as the database.
React for the frontend using TypeScript, Vite, and Chakra UI.
Docker Compose for development    and production.
Other features like JWT authentication, email-based password
recovery, CI/CD with GitHub Actions, and more.

Problem:
When I click on the "New Signature Request" link in the sidebar, I get a 404 Oops! Page not found. error with no sidebar or other elements displayed. However, other sidebar links work correctly and load their respective pages.
Here is the relevant code:
Route Tree Configuration (frontend/src/routeTree.gen.ts):
import { Route as rootRoute } from './routes/__root'
import { Route as ResetPasswordImport } from './routes/reset-password'
import { Route as RecoverPasswordImport } from './routes/recover-password'
import { Route as LoginImport } from './routes/login'
import { Route as LayoutImport } from './routes/_layout'
import { Route as LayoutIndexImport } from './routes/_layout/index'
import { Route as LayoutSettingsImport } from './routes/_layout/settings'
import { Route as LayoutItemsImport } from './routes/_layout/items'
import { Route as LayoutDocumentsImport } from './routes/_layout/documents'
import { Route as LayoutSignatureRequestsImport } from './routes/_layout/signature_requests'
import { Route as LayoutCreateRouteImport } from './routes/_layout/create_signature_request'
import { Route as LayoutAdminImport } from './routes/_layout/admin'

const ResetPasswordRoute = ResetPasswordImport.update({ path: '/reset-password', getParentRoute: () => rootRoute })
const RecoverPasswordRoute = RecoverPasswordImport.update({ path: '/recover-password', getParentRoute: () => rootRoute })
const LoginRoute = LoginImport.update({ path: '/login', getParentRoute: () => rootRoute })
const LayoutRoute = LayoutImport.update({ id: '/_layout', getParentRoute: () => rootRoute })
const LayoutIndexRoute = LayoutIndexImport.update({ path: '/', getParentRoute: () => LayoutRoute })
const LayoutSettingsRoute = LayoutSettingsImport.update({ path: '/settings', getParentRoute: () => LayoutRoute })
const LayoutItemsRoute = LayoutItemsImport.update({ path: '/items', getParentRoute: () => LayoutRoute })
const LayoutDocumentsRoute = LayoutDocumentsImport.update({ path: '/documents', getParentRoute: () => LayoutRoute })
const LayoutSignatureRequestsRoute = LayoutSignatureRequestsImport.update({ path: '/signature_requests', getParentRoute: () => LayoutRoute })
const LayoutCreateSignatureRequestRoute = LayoutCreateRouteImport.update({ path: '/new_signature_requests', getParentRoute: () => LayoutRoute })
const LayoutAdminRoute = LayoutAdminImport.update({ path: '/admin', getParentRoute: () => LayoutRoute })

export const routeTree = rootRoute.addChildren([
  LayoutRoute.addChildren([
    LayoutAdminRoute,
    LayoutDocumentsRoute,
    LayoutSignatureRequestsRoute,
    LayoutCreateSignatureRequestRoute,
    LayoutItemsRoute,
    LayoutSettingsRoute,
    LayoutIndexRoute,
  ]),
  LoginRoute,
  RecoverPasswordRoute,
  ResetPasswordRoute,
])

Sidebar Configuration (frontend/src/components/Common/SidebarItems.tsx):
import { Box, Flex, Icon, Text, useColorModeValue } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { Link } from "@tanstack/react-router";
import React from "react";
import { FiBriefcase, FiFileText, FiHome, FiPlus, FiSettings, FiUsers } from "react-icons/fi";
import { useQueryClient } from "react-query";
import type { UserOut } from "../../client";

const items = [
  { icon: FiHome, title: "Dashboard", path: "/" },
  { icon: FiBriefcase, title: "Items", path: "/items" },
  { icon: FiFileText, title: "Documents", path: "/documents" },
  { icon: FiFileText, title: "Signature Requests", path: "/signature_requests" },
  { icon: FiPlus, title: "New Signature Request", path: "/new_signature_requests" },
  { icon: FiSettings, title: "User Settings", path: "/settings" },
];

interface SidebarItemsProps {
  onClose?: () => void;
}

const SidebarItems: React.FC<SidebarItemsProps> = ({ onClose }) => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const textColor = useColorModeValue("ui.main", "ui.white");
  const bgActive = useColorModeValue("#E2E8F0", "#4A5568");
  const currentUser = queryClient.getQueryData<UserOut>("currentUser");

  const finalItems = currentUser?.is_superuser ? [...items, { icon: FiUsers, title: "Admin", path: "/admin" }] : items;

  const listItems = finalItems.map((item) => (
    <Flex
      as={Link}
      to={item.path}
      w="100%"
      p={2}
      key={item.title}
      activeProps={{ style: { background: bgActive, borderRadius: "12px" } }}
      color={textColor}
      onClick={onClose}
    >
      <Icon as={item.icon} alignSelf="center" />
      <Text ml={2}>{item.title}</Text>
    </Flex>
  ));

  return <Box>{listItems}</Box>;
};

export default SidebarItems;

Create Signature Request Route (frontend/src/routes/_layout/create_signature_request.tsx):
import { createRoute } from "@tanstack/react-router";
import CreateSignatureRequestWizard from "../../components/SignatureRequests/CreateSignatureRequestWizard";
import { Route as LayoutRoute } from "../_layout";

export const Route = createRoute({
  getParentRoute: () => LayoutRoute,
  path: "/new_signature_requests",
  component: CreateSignatureRequestWizard,
});

Create Signature Request Wizard Component (frontend/src/components/SignatureRequests/CreateSignatureRequestWizard.tsx):
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Box, Button, Container, Flex, Heading, Input, Select, VStack, Checkbox, Textarea, useToast } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { SignatureRequestCreate } from "../../client/models/SignatureRequestCreate";
import { initiateSignatureRequest } from "../../client/services/SignatureRequestsService";
import StepIndicator from "../Common/StepIndicator";
import DocumentSelect from "../Common/DocumentSelect";
import SignatoryForm from "../Common/SignatoryForm";
import FieldForm from "../Common/FieldForm";

const initialRequest: SignatureRequestCreate = {
  name: "",
  delivery_mode: "",
  ordered_signers: false,
  reminder_settings: { interval_in_days: 0, max_occurrences: 0, timezone: "" },
  expiration_date: "",
  message: "",
  expiry_date: "",
  signatories: [],
  documents: [],
};

const CreateSignatureRequestWizard = () => {
  const [step, setStep] = useState(0);
  const [signatureRequest, setSignatureRequest] = useState<SignatureRequestCreate>(initialRequest);
  const toast = useToast();

  const handleNext = () => setStep((prev) => prev + 1);
  const handlePrev = () => setStep((prev) => prev - 1);
  const handleInputChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
    const { name, value, type } = e.target;
    if (type === "checkbox") {
      setSignatureRequest((prev) => ({ ...prev, [name]: (e.target as HTMLInputElement).checked }));
    } else {
      setSignatureRequest((prev) => ({ ...prev, [name]: value }));
    }
  };

  const handleDocumentSelect = (documents: number[]) => {
    setSignatureRequest((prev) => ({ ...prev, documents }));
  };

  const handleSignatoriesChange = (signatories: SignatureRequestCreate["signatories"]) => {
    setSignatureRequest((prev) => ({ ...prev, signatories }));
  };

  const handleFieldsChange = (fields: SignatureRequestCreate["signatories"][0]["fields"]) => {
    const updatedSignatories = [...signatureRequest.signatories];
    if (updatedSignatories.length > 0) {
      updatedSignatories[0].fields = fields;
      setSignatureRequest((prev) => ({ ...prev, signatories: updatedSignatories }));
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    try {
      await initiateSignatureRequest(signatureRequest);
      toast({
        title: "Signature request created.",
        description: "Your signature request has been created successfully.",
        status: "success",
        duration: 5000,
        isClosable: true,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      toast({
        title: "Error creating signature request.",
        description: "An error occurred while creating the signature request.",
        status: "error",
        duration: 5000,
        isClosable: true,
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <Container maxW="container.md">
      <Heading as="h1" mb={4}>Create Signature Request</Heading>
      <StepIndicator currentStep={step} steps={["Document", "Signatories", "Fields", "Review"]} />
      <Box my={4}>
        {step === 0 && <DocumentSelect selectedDocuments={signatureRequest.documents} onSelect={handleDocumentSelect} />}
        {step === 1 && <SignatoryForm signatories={signatureRequest.signatories} onChange={handleSignatoriesChange} />}
        {step === 2 && <FieldForm fields={signatureRequest.signatories[0]?.fields || []} onChange={handleFieldsChange} />}
        {step === 3 && (
          <VStack spacing={4} align="stretch">
            <Input type="text" name="name" value={signatureRequest.name} onChange={handleInputChange} placeholder="Request Name" />
            <Select name="delivery_mode" value={signatureRequest.delivery_mode} onChange={handleInputChange}>
              <option value="">Select Delivery Mode</option>
              <option value="email">Email</option>
              <option value="direct">Direct</option>
              <option value="sms">SMS</option>
            </Select>
            <Checkbox name="ordered_signers" isChecked={signatureRequest.ordered_signers} onChange={handleInputChange}>Ordered Signers</Checkbox>
            <Input type="datetime-local" name="expiration_date" value={signatureRequest.expiration_date} onChange={handleInputChange} />
            <Textarea name="message" value={signatureRequest.message} onChange={handleInputChange} placeholder="Message" />
          </VStack>
        )}
      </Box>
      <Flex justify="space-between" mt={4}>
        {step > 0 && <Button onClick={handlePrev}>Previous</Button>}
        {step < 3 && <Button onClick={handleNext}>Next</Button>}
        {step === 3 && <Button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</Button>}
      </Flex>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default CreateSignatureRequestWizard;

Service for Signature Requests (frontend/src/client/services/SignatureRequestsService.ts):
import { OpenAPI } from "../core/OpenAPI";
import { request } from "../core/request";
import { SignatureRequestCreate } from "../models/SignatureRequestCreate";
import { SignatureRequestRead } from "../models/SignatureRequestRead";

export const initiateSignatureRequest = (data: SignatureRequestCreate): Promise<SignatureRequestRead> => {
  return request<SignatureRequestRead>(OpenAPI, {
    method: "POST",
    url: "/api/v1/signature_requests/",
    body: data,
    mediaType: "application/json",
  });
};

export const fetchSignatureRequests = (): Promise<SignatureRequestRead[]> => {
  return request<SignatureRequestRead[]>(OpenAPI, {
    method: "GET",
    url: "/api/v1/signature_requests/",
  });
};

Problem Explanation:

Clicking on "New Signature Request" in the sidebar navigates to a 404
page with no sidebar or other elements.
All other sidebar links work correctly.
The path defined for "New Signature Request" in the route is /new_signature_requests.

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Verified that the route path /new_signature_requests is consistent
across the route configuration and sidebar items.
Ensured the CreateSignatureRequestWizard component is correctly
imported and used in the create route.

Request:

Could anyone provide insights into what might be causing the 404
error specifically for the "New Signature Request" page?
Any suggestions on additional debugging steps or corrections in the
route configuration would be appreciated.

Thank you!
